# Remotely manage .net processes

Tags: c#, wmi, jmx

I am going to be deploying a solution which includes a number of small long running processes which will live on a number of boxes.  I wanted to develop a central dashboard for managing these processes and was looking for a good way to do so.  I would want to get some counters from the processes and monitor things like memory usage and uptime as well as remotely restart them.  In java I would use JMX and I was wondering if there was a similar technology in the .net space.  So far I have come across

- [NetMX](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=NetMX)
- [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx)

WMI looks to really be more focused towards unmanaged code.  NexMX seems to be ideal but not heavily used.  Does anybody have some experiences doing something similar they could share?  Any other technologies I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of NetMX, version 0.7 might have something to do with it.  WMI is quite adroit at monitoring .NET apps as well as unmanaged apps.  Fire up Perfmon.exe to see the .NET performance counters at work.  Queryable with WMI, experiment with [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en).

Comment: WMI is pretty good on .NET; it's not just performance counters. You can expose your .NET objects directly to WMI on the server side, and run queries over them and access their properties remotely.